# Surjective map to quasi-projective variety with affine spaces of varying dimension as fibres

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth complex quasi-projective variety over $\mathbb C$ with a stratification into locally closed subvarieties $X_0, ..., X_k$, where $X_0$ is open and $\dim X_j < \dim X_i$ whenever $i < j$.

Let $\widetilde X = \bigcup_{i = 0}^k X_i \times \mathbb A^i$ and consider the map $f \colon \widetilde X \to X$, given by projection to the first factor.

Then $f$ is surjective with affine spaces as fibres. Is there a natural way of thinking about the space $\widetilde X$ (including a natural topology on $\widetilde X$) and the map $f$?

Comment: Do you have a reason for thinking about this space? I've never heard of it before, so it's hard to intuit why one might care or what such a structure would be useful for.

Comment: @TabesBridges I was trying to understand how the dimension of fibres in a morphism of varieties can vary, and how the fibres can be glued together. The space in the question could be viewed as a simple example of a generalization of affine bundle (which would be given by a map $f \colon \widetilde X \to X$ where $X$ can be covered by opens $\{ U_i \}$ such that $f^{-1} (U_i) \simeq U_i \times \mathbb A^n$). Varying the dimension of the fibre — even in the case when $X$ is affine — seems to be less obvious. It looks like this space could appear in nature, but I'm not sure (hence my question).

Comment: Here's a simple example: let $X$ be the result of blowing up $\mathbb P^2$ at a point $p$ and deleting a point from the exceptional divisor. This is a morphism most of whose fibers are single points (which you can think of as $\mathbb A^0$) and whose fiber over $p$ is $\mathbb A^1$.

Comment: Thanks, but can you also come up with an example that has fibres of dimension 0, 1 and 2?

Comment: Sure: start with $\mathbb P^3$, take a point $p$ and a disjoint line $L$, and now blow $\mathbb P^3$ up along both of them up (order doesn't matter since they are disjoint.). The fiber over $p$ is a copy of $\mathbb P^2$, while the inverse image of $L$ is the Hirzebruch surface $\mathbb P(N_{L/\mathbb P^3}) = \mathbb P(\mathcal O(1) \oplus \mathcal O(1)) = \mathbb P(\mathcal O \oplus \mathcal O) = \mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1 \to L$, so the fibers over points of $L$ are projective lines...

Comment: ...Now just delete a line from the exceptional $\mathbb P^2$ and a section from the exceptional $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$ to make the fibers affine, and you have your example. You should be able to see how to generalize this construction now to get examples with fibers of any combination of dimensions.

Comment: @TabesBridges I see, great. Can one also get the dimensions to "add up"? For example something like dimension 1 on the coordinate axes in $\mathbb C^2$, but dimension 2 at the origin.

Comment: You can only blow up points on surfaces, and those will only yield exceptional curves. If you blow up one or more of the coordinate lines in $\mathbb C^3$ (the lines with ideals $\langle x,y\rangle$, $\langle x,z\rangle$, and $\langle y,z\rangle$) you will get $\mathbb P^1$ bundles over the lines (I'm assuming you blow up the lines one at a time; I'm not sure this depends on order, but the resulting varieties will be isomorphic). I believe after doing this you have a chain of $3$ copies of $\mathbb P^1$ lying over the origin, and blowing up one point on this will produce an exceptional plane.

Comment: So I think you will have a rather strange fiber over the origin consisting of a plane and three lines linked in a chain; this is not equidimensional of dimension $2$, but it is of dimension $2$ if you define the dimension of such a scheme to be the maximal dimension of its irreducible components (which I think is standard).